# Lebesgue decomposition and Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have problems computing the decomposition $\nu=\rho+l$
 and dervative $\frac{d\mu}{dl}$ in the following cases:

1. $\nu=\lambda,\space\mu=\delta_{2},$ where $\delta_{2}(x)=1$ if $x=2$ and zero in other case, and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.
2. $\nu=\lambda,\space\mu=10\lambda,$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.
3. $\nu=\delta_{2},\space\mu=\delta_{2}+\delta_{3}.$$

So, we need to use Radon-Nikodym theorem: every measure above is $\sigma-$finite, so for this theorem we can guarantee such decomposition, which is unique. But I can't see how to give explicitly the decomposition and the derivative.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced

Comment: I am unable to understand the question. In 1) if you are decomposing $\nu =\lambda$ with respect to Lebesgue measure you get $0+\lambda$. Where does $\mu$ come in? Is the question about $\frac {d\mu} {dl}$ a separate question not related to Lebesgue decomposition of $\nu$?